# Shape of tensor after tf.layers.Dense?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, deep-learning, regression

I'm making a DNN that solves a regression problem.

First I load a pre-trained VGG16 network, and than I make a few fully connected hidden layers. The last layer has one node which outputs a scalar.

I thought the shape of the output would have be something like [batch_size] or [batch_size, 1].

But when I call ...

```
...

fc5 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc4, units=1)

print(tf.shape(fc5))
print(fc5.get_shape())
```

... I get:

*> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)*

*> (?, ?, ?, 1)*

Can someone please explain this? Why does the shape has the first three dimensions, shouldn't `tf.layers.dense` make this a scalar or a list of scalars?

---

**EDIT:**

vgg_layer7_out shapes:

*> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)*

*> (?, ?, ?, 4096)*

fc1 shape:

*> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)*

*> (?, ?, ?, 1024)*

...

fc4 shape:

*> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)*

*> (?, ?, ?, 10)*

---

**Code for fc layers:**

```
fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=vgg_layer7_out, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.elu, bias_initializer=init, kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=reg, bias_regularizer=reg)

drop1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob)

fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(drop1, 128, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu, weights_initializer=init, weights_regularizer=reg)

drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, keep_prob)

fc3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(drop2, 50, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu, weights_initializer=init, weights_regularizer=reg)

drop3 = tf.nn.dropout(fc3, keep_prob)

fc4 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(drop3, 10, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu, weights_initializer=init, weights_regularizer=reg)

drop2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc4, keep_prob)

fc5 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=drop2, units=1, activation=None)
```

Comment: What is the shape of fc4?

Comment: Thanks, it's added now in the edit.

Comment: I think the reason is fc1 is computed from 4d `vgg_layer7_out` rather from it's flattened version `flatt`.

Comment: You are right, it has to be flatten. Post the answer. I never got an error when the shape was (?,?,?,1), how do I know if everything is OK now, the loss is decreasing perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dimitiry said, I forgot to flatten it... You could also use the `tf.squeeze` function before calling the loss func laster.